Replacing Concrete Pool Decking
My concrete pool decking needs to be replaced. I've had three concrete companies come give me estimates. The first told me it was fine to pour new concrete over the old concrete. The second told me it was important to break up the concrete but it didn't need to be removed. The third told me it was best to remove all of the old concrete and pour entirely fresh.
Who is right?

If those are cosmetic/surface cracks the first one is right

You got three estimates and three different answers from contractors that visited the site. What makes you think you'll get the "right" answer from here?  Personally, I think removing the old, recompacting the area and adding new would be the way to go.

Kinda depends why it needs to be replaced, and what failed to cause that to be the case. Which is rather hard to tell from here. If there are structural issues with the sub-base, which caused the current slab/deck to fail, those need to be corrected. If it's a cosmetic replacement only, pouring on the old slab may be fine.
